# Objects share same values, even when "new" is used

Tags: java

I'm trying to do something pretty simple but I can't seem to get it to work.  I'm trying to iterate through an ArrayList but my for loop is always returning the same value when I output the results to the terminal.

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Contact{
    public static ArrayList<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    public static String name;
    public static String phoneNumber;
    public static String email;
    private static int idCounter = 0;
    private final int contactID;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Contact bob = new Contact("bob","8493483943","jo@g.com");
        Contact joe = new Contact("joe","940389439","something@g.com");
        ArrayList<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();
        contacts.add(bob);
        contacts.add(joe);
        for (Contact person : contacts) {
            System.out.println(person.idCounter);
            System.out.println(person.name);
            System.out.println(person.phoneNumber);
            System.out.println(person.email);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public Contact(String name,String phoneNumber,String email){
        this.contactID = idCounter++;
        this.name = name;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

The above code always returns this when I run the code:

```
2
joe
940389439
something@g.com

2
joe
940389439
something@g.com
```

It returns the same information even though I've added 2 different objects into the ArrayList.

When I do this inside the for loop:

```
System.out.println(person);
```

It returns a Contact object with different id's.

I'm a little confused as to why this is happening as I'm assuming I'm not referencing the same variable or object here, or that I'm doing something wrong in my loop.

If anyone could help me explain what's going on that'd be great, thanks!

Comment: Your 4th line `public static ArrayList<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();` should be deleted, since you're redeclaring it.

Comment: @AnubianNoob Even if I delete it, it returns the same values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your attributes are static: name, phoneNumber and email. Remove static keyword [static keyword make classlevel attributes] :)

Answer (score 0):

All your class variables are static. This means they will be overwritten ones you create the second object.